# How can I set the retry count on sqs on my lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I deployed SQS fifo queue and a lambda function use source mapping to trigger the lambda from message queue. I have checked some configuration regarding retry on failed messages. But I can't find an exact `retry count` configuration.

There is a message retention period (default 4 days) and visibility timeout. What I can think of is to use these two configuration to control the retry time.

Another solution is to use dead letter queue and configure `maxReceiveCount`. That means if a message retried `maxReceiveCount` times, it will be deleted and put to DLQ. Is this correct?

Are my two solutions valid or whether there is any better way to configure?

Comment: Retry count means you want to process the message again and again for certain number of times even when it is processed successfully?

Comment: Not really chetan. If a lambda gives success response message will be automatically deleted from queue

Comment: In that case you can use DLQ with max receive count also with Visibility timeout. So that if message is not processed successfully by lambda for max receive count times it will be pushed to DLQ. And you can set an alert in DLQ to know if any message not processed successfully. Visibility timeout will put the message back to queue if lambda is not able to process it within that time so that it will be picked up again for processing.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes your understand is right

Comment: You can also check `ApproximateReceiveCount` attribute value of sqs message in lambda function and delete it when it reaches certain threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second solution you've mentioned is the recommended one.

The first solution will also work by setting (visibility timeout = message retention period/required retry attempts)

Comment: If I use the second solution, that means I can ignore the `retention period`?

Comment: Yeah you can leave it. It'll have the default value of 4 days